# Number of samples vs Number of features

Tags: classification, sample-size, feature-selection

I've got a set of two classes with 4000 observations total. I've a set of 63 features to construct a predictor.

My question is, is there a relation that would prevent overfiting for having too much dimensions? I mean a maximum number of features per number of observations in training?

Comment: not what you're asking, but you might want to try maximum margin classifiers, like SVMs, as they often have a nice resistance to over-fitting in high dimensional problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, you can actually calculate an upper bound on the test error (generalization error), if your sample is really *iid*. This is what [VC theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension), for example, deals with. However, the main problem is that this depends on the type of classifier/model you use. The more complex your model is, the more samples you will need. In VC theory, there is a concept called the *VC dimension*, that quantifies the complexity of the model.

In practice however, this is quite difficult to do, because: You need to know the VC dimension of your model, which might not be easily attainable; your data may not be *iid*; most importantly, you only get an upper bound, which might be quite wide and therefore not useful.

So in practice, you usually cannot know in advance how many features/samples are enough without having the data.